# How to fix IntelliJ Idea stuck on "Preparing WSL build environment..."?

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 with windows WSL, and have installed JDK 19.01 and Maven inside this, and have imported a file from the WSL into IntelliJ Idea to work on, however once I run a class, IntelliJ "builds" **for upwards of half an hour**, hanging on the messages of "Executing pre-compile tasks..." and "Preparing WSL build environment...". Obviously this is a pain and I need to know how to fix it.

[image: IntelliJ version 2022.2.3]

I've tried to reinstall my JDK in Ubuntu and set the JAVA_HOME variable, which I've checked and have no issues with. I've tried to reinstall IntelliJ, and disabled my firewall/made exceptions, and I've changed the SDK being used inside IntelliJ, all to no success.

Here are logs from inside the Ubuntu terminal showing my JDK and Maven installations:

```
user@user  \~  mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.6.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 19.0.1, vendor: Private Build, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-19-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-wsl2", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
user@user  \~  javac -version
javac 19.0.1
user@user  \~  java -version
openjdk version "19.0.1" 2022-10-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 19.0.1+10-Ubuntu-1ubuntu122.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.1+10-Ubuntu-1ubuntu122.04, mixed mode, sharing)
user@user  \~  echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-19-openjdk-amd64
user@user  \~  which java
/usr/bin/java
user@user  \~  which javac
/usr/bin/javac
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable the real-time antivirus monitoring. It's a [known issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8995).

Comment: Also important to check this setting again after a reboot. I don't know why but in my the Real-time protection always automatically get reenabled after after a reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Remove fsnotifier.exe and idea64.exe in windows defender or follow the directions in this post:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-293604/IntelliJ-is-hanging-during-build-process-and-indexing-process-when-working-on-the-WSL-projects.#focus=Comments-27-6180537.0-0

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Disabling real-time antivirus for Windows (while it works) should be a "temporary" fix. Stay safe out there!